# Как выполнить команду с помощью модуля os от имени администратора?

Tags: python, консоль, python-os

Мне нужно выполнить команду через модуль `os` (`os.system()`), но её можно выполнить только от имени администратора.

Как её выполнить от имени администратора через модуль os? В интернете искал - не нашёл.

Comment: @Интик а можно ли как то проверить в коде питона, запущена ли программа от имени администратора, чтобы например если не с админки то писалось "Запустите программу от имени администратора", и тд?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```
import os

os.system('powershell Start-Process "КОМАНДА" -Verb RunAs')
```